# How to kill a scan operation in hbase shell without Ctrl-C

Tags: shell, hbase, irb, control-c

Sometimes when I run a `scan '<tablename>`. I see a continuous flood of data being printed because the table is big. I want to kill the process that print the data. Is there a way to do it other than `Ctrl-C`? because `Ctrl-C` kills the shell process and I don't want to exit the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use scan with LIMIT to limit the scan output on shell :

scan 'table', LIMIT => 5

This will show you only 5 rows. You could also press ctlr+s to hold the scan, if you have done a full scan and want to hold on at a specific row.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question as asked though. In the case where you issue a 'scan' command and accidentally forget it will return thousands/millions of rows, is there a solution to interrupt it or not?

Comment: @smci, 
Why does an asterisk sign show at the end of the hbase shell prompt Instead of > after typing a command ending as ';'?
How do I fix the prompt ending with an asterisk sign without exit hbase shell?

Comment: @smci Thanks. Somebody told me using ctrl+d can stop an incomplete command. It works.

Comment: @JuliaChang: that's good to know, presumably with current version, because when I used hbase several years ago it didn't.