# How to stop command running in hbase shell and not exit hbase shell

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

In some times I want quit from my running command in HBase shell, such as a scan ops usually take too much time.

So I want to stop running this command, but I don't want exit HBase shell.

The usual way for me to stop the running command, I used Ctrl+C, which can stop the running command, but it also exit from HBase shell, then I need to take more time to reEnter the HBase shell.

Is there any better way to solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a scan operation in hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047174/how-to-kill-a-scan-operation-in-hbase-shell)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> pauses the screen(console), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> resumes it back, it can be used to control console output of any application (like cat longfile.txt etc.) not just hbase shell.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control#Applications

Another alternative option is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> which suspends the current foreground job the impact will be a paused screen. To resume the suspended task just press `fg` to bring it back to foreground.

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-job-control-commands-in-linux-bg-fg-and-ctrlz/